# Strange behavior of datetime.replace and pytz

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

When running the following code:

```
d = datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 8)
print d.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Asia/Jerusalem'))
```

I expect it to print `2014-01-01 08:00:00+02:00`, but instead it prints `2014-01-01 08:00:00+02:21` (notice the strange timezone). Can someone please explain to me this strange behavior?

BTW when I print `pytz.timezone('Asia/Jerusalem').localize(d)`, it prints '2014-01-01 08:00:00+02:00' as expected.

Comment: Don't use `datetime.replace()`; use `timezone.localize()`.

Comment: I already know that, but I wonder why the above code behaves like it does.

Comment: Because the `pytz` timezones contain not just the *current* timezone offsets but also historical; e.g. they'll work correctly when you use them for a date sometime in the past. `datetime` doesn't know how to handle this correctly.

Comment: In other words, the `Asia/Jerusalem` *at some point in the past* used an offset that was 21 minutes off.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters. I don't really understand why you marked my question as duplicate as the other question is "how to do something" and my question is "why do I get this result"

Comment: I did make too quick an assumption that the answer there detailed that too. I'll update it.

Comment: Perhaps things are done differently in [tag:python] questions, but I would only close as a duplicate if the *questions* are identical, not just that the other answer contains the necessary info. Is this a common moderating technique in this tag? (I'm new here)

Comment: Isn't this all explained in the pytz documentation?